# Jetty error "IllegalStateException: No Method: <Call name="addBefore"> ... on class ...Configuration$ClassList"

Tags: java, jetty, jetty-9

I am using an external jetty version 9.4.35.v20201120. I am getting this error in my Eclipse. Not sure why! Researched a lot but not able to fix it. Can any help here?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Method: <Call name="addBefore"><Arg name="addBefore" type="java.lang.String">org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration</Arg><Arg><Array type="java.lang.String"><Item>org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration</Item></Array></Arg></Call> on class org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Configuration$ClassList
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.call(XmlConfiguration.java:950)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.call(XmlConfiguration.java:945)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:364)
    at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.jetty9.Jetty9LauncherMain.configure(Jetty9LauncherMain.java:85)
    at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.common.AbstractJettyLauncherMain.configure(AbstractJettyLauncherMain.java:144)
    at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.common.AbstractJettyLauncherMain.launch(AbstractJettyLauncherMain.java:75)
    at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.jetty9.Jetty9LauncherMain.main(Jetty9LauncherMain.java:42)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: addBefore
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.call(XmlConfiguration.java:987)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.call(XmlConfiguration.java:942)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you also include some of the code that you think might have caused the problem?

Comment: I got this same error, after I set the "Use Jetty at path" in Jetty Webapp for my project which is located in "Run Configuration" of Eclipse.
I switched it back to "Use Jetty provided by launcher plugin" and the error was gone. Still looking as what actually happened there.

Comment: this issue is due to the jar files that are required to run the jetty. we need to add some jars in the classpath to resolve this issue. But I am not sure which jar actually works for this.